# Shortcut for jumping to the first/last match of find search in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Sometimes I got a large number of matches in Find Bar, and I want to jump to the first/last match when the current match in the near middle of the matches.

Is there a shortcut to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the top of the page with the find bar, thus it will show the first match. To match the last match then it is **ctrl + shift + g** (previous match).

Ref: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't seem to exist (Boo Chrome!, it is super simple useful and important please implement it!).

The best we can do seems to be:

If the find bar is not open yet, open it and type. We then see the following (somewhat complex and weird) behavior: It takes us to the first match from the current cursor position. It will say 1 at the top but it will not actually be at the first global match. Hitting enter or Ctrl-g will then take you to the first match. Hitting Ctrl-Shift-g instead will take you to the last match.

If the find bar is currently open at some random match it is more complicated to go to the first or last match again. A quick way is to add a character such that no match exists anymore such as $ followed by backspace to remove it again. This will initiate a new search and take you to the first match again.